# How to extract part of a string using only variables in a batch file?

Tags: batch-file, variables, environment-variables, backup

Maybe I'm trying to oversimplify things. Having trouble removing part of a variable to be used as a path name. Goal is to transfer everything from folders (and sub) on multiple windows profiles  to a single profile.

I can copy all the content, but cannot tell it where to place it. Also happen to be trying to use robocopy instead for the first time. I want to make a folders on the desktop that are named the username of every user on the device, then copy all content.

```
for /d %%a in (C:\Users\*) do (

     set var=%%a
     var=${var#*s/ }

mkdir "%USERPROFILE%\Desktop\Backup\%var%\folderx"

xcopy "%%a\Desktop\folderx" "%USERPROFILE%\Desktop\Backup\%var%\folderx" /E /Y
)
```

Notes:

1. Not sure the best way to remove C:\Users\ so I leave just the username as a variable (it assumes var is a command)
2. I'm trying to do it without having to write a string to file and read it back
3. This assumes the Backup folder is already created

Comment: Open a [command prompt](https://www.howtogeek.com/235101/), run `for /?` and read the output help. `%~nxI` references the string after last backslash of the file/folder string assigned currently to loop variable `I` which would be in your case the name of the folder in `%HomeDrive%\Users`. In your case you would have to use in the batch file `%%~nxa` to reference the directory name and you know after reading help of __FOR__ and looking on this modifier string why `a` and `A` is no good choice for a loop variable. Loop variable is case-sensitive, but the modifiers are case-insensitive.

Answer (score 0):

Still not sure how to strip it correctly. Just found it more efficient to not include the drive in the first place.

1. List item dir bare command to get name
2. changed C: to user variable in case installed on a different letter

```
FOR /f "tokens=*" %%a in ('dir /b /a:d-s-l "%SystemDrive%\Users"') DO (

    mkdir "%USERPROFILE%\Desktop\Backup\%%a\folderx"
    mkdir "%USERPROFILE%\Desktop\Backup\%%\foldery"

    xcopy "%SystemDrive%\Users\%%a\Desktop\folderx" "%USERPROFILE%\Desktop\Backup\%%a\folderx" /e /y
    xcopy "%SystemDrive%\Users\%%a\Desktop\foldery" "%USERPROFILE%\Desktop\Backup\%%a\foldery" /e /y

)
```

Strictly speaking, not an answer, but a cleaner solution to the root problem. Still not sure how to properly strip information.

Comment: `%HOMEDRIVE%` is usually the drive where the `Users` folder is located and `%SystemDrive%` is usually the drive where the `Windows` folder is located. Both folders are usually on the same drive, but not always.

Comment: I recommend to use `"eol=| delims="` instead of `"tokens=*"` to make sure really processing correct all folders output by __DIR__ including folders starting with one or more spaces or a semicolon (after 0 or more leading spaces). `"tokens=*"` results in first removing all leading/spaces tabs from captured line and ignoring the line if the remaining string starts with a semicolon. `"eol=| delims="` turns off line splitting behavior by definition of an empty list of delimiters and redefines end of line character to a vertical bar which no file/folder name can contain and so no ignored anymore.

Comment: It would be better to specify the target folder on both __XCOPY__ copy command lines with ``\`` at end before closing `"` to make it 100% clear for __XCOPY__ that the target is a directory and not a file. Then the two `mkdir` would not be necessary at all because of __XCOPY__ would create the target directory automatically before copying the files. BTW: The second `mkdir` misses the loop variable `a` after `%%`. Run `robocopy /?` in a command prompt window for help on this executable which should be used nowadays instead of `xcopy` executable.